# What does deploying "spot on" mean?

Tags: terminology, ingress

I recently started playing Ingress and overtook a few portals - then had a message from someone (on the same team) saying:

> We got turned over last night. Capture all you like but please deploy spot on. Cheers

What does "spot on" mean in this context?

(My initial thought was that it meant to deploy resonators as close as possible to the portal location, but I was under the impression that it was best to do the opposite - spread them out.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think they are telling you to deploy as far you can, so you have to deploy at 40m of distance from the portal. The resos will be at max distance positioned, so will be more "difficult" to destroy.

But as is said, "A picture is worth a thousand words:"

[image]

**EDIT:**

Is good to prevent attacks from UltraStrikes deploying 1 resonator at less than 40m, I ussually deploy more or less 1 resonator at 10/15m. With this type of deploy if someone attacks with ultras to the center of the portal, the range of attack of Ultra will hit the resonator, so it will make the portal attack the player.

Comment: Nice tip on ultra strikes!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's ingress specific. I think "spot on" here means correctly, that is with resonators nicely spread out as it's recommended.

The local guy is concerned that someone in the rush of destroying and capturing may deploy without care.